# Paypal embedded button behavior after checkout

Tags: php, button, paypal, transactions, behavior

I'm building a registration form through a third-party form creator online, and am planning on using the PayPal embedded "Buy now" button as my checkout process. I was wondering if anyone knew how the transactions are handled in Paypal when using this button? The accounting head here at my office is concerned that if I use this button method for payment the funds will go into a holding account within our Paypal account. Ideally what would happen is that the transaction would be automatically processed and the funds would be deposited into our bank account without her having to go into the Paypal account and manually process each transaction. Can anyone enlighten me on this process? This process will make or break me using this method of payment, so any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use PayPal, the fund will go into your PayPal account.

You can however, set up an auto sweep with paypal. This will take the funds every 24 hours and send them to your bank automatically.

There is no way to use the PayPal buttons and bypass Paypal completely.